# Standup an EC2 instance without keys using the CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

How do I create a CloudFormation stack that automatically stands-up an EC2 linux instance but the login to be made via a password and without any keys.

I found a tutorial to enable password authentication but It requires changing the data in sshd_config and restarting the instance and I'm not sure how to replicate that in an cloudformation stack.

Comment: You need to write user data that enabled password login for SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested by Mr. Paolo user-data is the way to go.

Your final user-data script will look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd
```

This will make sure password auth is enabled once your system boots up and performs user data operations.

Learn more about user data over this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently... I would create a custom AMI first with password authentication, and then launch this ami as any other instance. Only in the unique situation when it is not possible, I would go with `sed` => restart route